# Cannot add part for the specified URI because it is already in the package

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I am using NUGET Pack in teamcity to build a package. But it is creating the following error. I am using nuget teamcity version 2.2.1.

```
Step 2/2: Build Package (NuGet Pack) (14s)

[12:10:40][Step 2/2] Cleaning Z:\hgbuilds\IT\Build\packages

[12:10:40][Step 2/2] pack: Create NuGet package from UI\UI.Tour\UI.Tour.Web\UI.Tour.Web.csproj (14s)

[12:10:40][pack] NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.2.2.1.nupkg\tools\NuGet.exe pack Z:\hgbuilds\IT\UI\UI.Tour\UI.Tour.Web\Calrom.UI.InclusiveTour.Web.csproj -OutputDirectory Z:\hgbuilds\IT\Build\packages -BasePath Z:\hgbuilds\IT -Verbose -Version 1.0.0.7 -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Deploy-Test

[12:10:40][pack] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script2086270793558421822.cmd

[12:10:40][pack] in directory: Z:\hgbuilds\IT

[12:10:45][pack] WARNING: Option 'Verbose' has been deprecated. Use 'Verbosity' instead.

[12:10:45][pack] Attempting to build package from 'UI.Tour.Web.csproj'.

[12:10:45][pack] Packing files from 'Z:\hgbuilds\IT\UI\UI.Tour\UI.Tour.Web\bin'.

[12:10:46][pack] WARNING: Description was not specified. Using 'Description'.

[12:10:48][pack] content

[12:10:54][pack] Cannot add part for the specified URI because it is already in the package.

[12:10:54][pack] Process exited with code 1

[12:10:54][Step 2/2] Step Build Package (NuGet Pack) failed
```

Please guide what I am missing here.

Comment: +1, but if my answer doesn't help please could you post your nuspec file/more details?

Comment: I am using octopack. Cant see any nuspec file. It has added a package file with following contents
<packages>
  <package id="OctoPack" version="2.0.20" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages> and in NUGET Pack sending the package parameters specifying project file

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error but there were no issues in the csproj file. I was using typescript and was accidentally checking in the .js files. So at run-time another js file was being generated, thus there were two of each js files being added.

I found it by going through the team city build log and looking for duplicates. As they were "do not copy" there was no issue with a simple msbuild but as we just switched to using Octopack, cannot add multiple when nugeting a solution.....

**You can find the culprit (typescript or otherwise)** as it will be the first to appear after the "attempting to create line" (there could be many but finding them on at a time could be easier than doing it manually)
[image]

Comment: Thanks @GarethReid - we hit this same problem and your solution fixed it :)

Answer (score 5):

Edit the project file and make sure you do not have duplicate Reference Incudes or duplicate Content Includes. My issue was I had...

```
    <Reference Include="SCS.PickList, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>Bin\SCS.PickList.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

AND

```
<Content Include="Bin\SCS.PickList.dll" />
```

Once I removed the Content include it worked.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem for me too! I also got this issue because of an assembly reference in the project that occurred both as Reference and Content include in the *.csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem could be that Octopack is actually case sensitive. In my case VS Project had reference to the file with name in lower case letters
[such as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRvnw.png)

Comment: my problem was case sensitivity also. Typescript file with capitals was compiling to a js file with a filename that was the same but all lower case. Changing the case of the .js filename to match the .ts file fixed the issue

Comment: In my case, it as as obscure as having an old `/// <reference path="language-service.ts" />` line at the top of another file caused Language-Service.ts to compile to language-service.ts

Answer (score 1):

In my .nuspec file I had the lines equivalent to:

```
<file src="Source\MyCompany.ProjectA\**\*.cs" target="src" />
<file src="Source\MyCompany.ProjectB\**\*.cs" target="src" />
```

I got the error due to the **AssemblyInfo.cs** file being in both projects.

(This was to enable the creation of a NuGet Symbol Package.)

Comment: I had the same problem. To fix it, specify different target directories: target="src\ProjectA", target="src\ProjectB".

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because my files didn't have extensions.

```
<file src=".\LICENSE" target="" />
<file src=".\NOTICE" target="" />
```

My solution was to add a wildcard to the end of the file:

```
<file src=".\LICENSE*" target="" />
<file src=".\NOTICE*" target="" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have no idea how long it would have taken me to find this if not for your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

In your nuspec file do you have a file node specified?

```
<files>
    <file src="the_dll_for_your_csproj"/>
</files>
```

If so, is it possible that you have included (either explicitly or by wildcard) the dll for the csproj you are trying to build?