# Error while building vsix container in vs2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I am facing one unique issue with building VSIX project in VS2015. Project build is successful when I build normally. But when choose the option ""Create VSIX container while build" in project property, I am getting following errors in VS2015. Please help me out.

```
Error       The "CreateZipPackage" task failed unexpectedly.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create file because the specified file name is already in use.
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.AddFile(String zipFileName, CompressionMethodEnum compressionMethod, DeflateOptionEnum deflateOption)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.ContentTypeHelper.SaveToFile()
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.VsSDK.Build.Tasks.CreateZipPackage.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809704/cannot-add-part-for-the-specified-uri-because-it-is-already-in-the-package

Comment: @rene i dont think, that link has connection with my issue. Please provide me some relative example or solution

Comment: I think it has a link, maybe you can verify if any of the issues presented there applies to your *.csproj file. I can't imagine it has a different root cause. Maybe you can elaborate in an [edit] what might be special in your *.csproj, file-types, content, references etx.